# Parent-Child Communication in Angular2

Tags: angular

How can nested components communicate with each other in Angular 2?

Adding `@Parent()` to the constructor at any level breaks the app.

Given the following code, how can I grab the `message`'s from the GrandParent, Parent, Child, and GrandChild at each level?

> /client/grandparent

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {ParentCmp} from 'client/parent';
import {ChildCmp} from 'client/child';
import {GrandChildCmp} from 'client/grandchild';

@Component({
  selector: 'grand-parent'
})
@View({
  template: `
  <div style="background-color: lightgreen; padding: 10px;">
    <h1>Grand-Parent</h1>
    <p>Parent: {{parentMessage}}</p>
    <p>Child: {{childMessage}}</p>
    <p>Grand-Child: {{grandChildMessage}}</p>

    <parent></parent>
  </div>
  `,
  directives: [ParentCmp]
})
class GrandParent {
  message:string;
  parentMessage:string;
  childMessage: string;
  grandChildMessage: string;

  constructor() {
    this.message = "message from grandparent";
    //this.parentMessage = parent.message;
    //this.childMessage = child.message;
    //this.grandChildMessage = grandChild.message;
  }
}

bootstrap(GrandParent);
```

> /client/parent

```
import {Component, View, Parent} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {GrandParentCmp} from 'client/grandparent';
import {ChildCmp} from 'client/child';
import {GrandChildCmp} from 'client/grandchild';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent'
})
@View({
  template: `
  <div style="background-color: lightblue; padding: 10px;">
    <p>Grand-Parent: {{grandParentMessage}}</p>
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <p>Child: {{childMessage}}</p>
    <p>Grand-Child: {{grandChildMessage}}</p>

    <child></child>
  </div>
  `,
  directives: [ChildCmp]
})
export class ParentCmp {
  message:string;
  grandParentMessage:string;
  childMessage:string;
  grandChildMessage:string;

  constructor() {
    this.message = "message from parent";
    //this.grandParentMessage = grandParent.message;
    //this.childMessage = child.message;
    //this.grandChildMessage = grandChild.message;

  }
}
```

> /client/child

```
import {Component, View, Host} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {GrandParentCmp} from 'client/grandparent';
import {ParentCmp} from 'client/parent';
import {GrandChildCmp} from 'client/grandchild';

@Component({
  selector: 'child'
})
@View({
  template: `
  <div style="background-color: orange; padding: 10px;">
    <p>GrandParent: {{grandParentMessage}}</p>
    <p>Parent: {{parentMessage}}</p>
    <h1>Child</h1>
    <p>Grand-Child: {{grandChildMessage}}</p>

    <grand-child></grand-child>
  </div>
  `,
  directives: [GrandChildCmp]
})
export class ChildCmp {
  message:string;
  grandParentMessage:string;
  parentMessage:string;
  grandChildMessage:string;

  constructor() {
    this.message = "message from child";
    //this.grandParentMessage = grandParent.message;
    //this.parentMessage = parent.message;
    //this.grandChildMessage = grandChild.message;
  }
}
```

/client/grandchild

```
import {Component, View, Host} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {GrandParentCmp} from 'client/grandparent';
import {ParentCmp} from 'client/parent';
import {ChildCmp} from 'client/child';

@Component({
  selector: 'grand-child'
})
@View({
  template: `
  <div style="background-color: lightgrey; padding: 10px;">
    <p>Grand-Parent: {{grandParentMessage}}</p>
    <p>Parent: {{parentMessage}}</p>
    <p>Child</p>
    <h1>Grand-Child: {{grandChildMessage}}</h1>

    <child></child>
  </div>
  `
})
export class GrandChildCmp {
  message:string;
  grandParentMessage:string;
  parentMessage:string;
  grandChildMessage:string;

  constructor() {
    this.message = "message from grandchild";
    //this.grandParentMessage = grandParent.message;
    //this.parentMessage = parent.message;
    //this.grandChildMessage = grandChild.message;
  }
}
```

I've included a link to the [Github Repo](https://github.com/ShMcK/Angular2-Underderstanding/tree/master/parent-child).

Comment: What version of angular are you using? `@Parent` was removed on alpha29 so you should try with `@Ancestor` (which will be replaced with `@Host` from alpha34+)

Comment: Thanks. alpha-33, I was trying @Host, but no luck. Good to know it's coming soon. What about for Children?

Comment: For children you can use [Query](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/IQueryList-interface.html)

Comment: I understand how it should work based on [the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3cda7128d0a74661511390f4713682973e63b1fc/modules/angular2/src/core/annotations_impl/annotations.ts), but I'm still unable to create a working example. Any chance you could provide a more complete code example?

Comment: A service would help for this kind of tasks - including sharing state.