# Angular 2 DI can't resolve parameters, HTTP client module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-httpclient

I am learning to use Angular 2 and have reached a point here I am stuck with the error below. This only appears since adding the httpClientModule and trying to make a http get request from a components ngInit. The app is using angular 4.3.4.

```
Can't resolve all parameters for BlogComponent: (?).
```

contents of app.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';


import { appRoutes } from './routes'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BlogComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

contents of the blog component ts file which is throwing the error

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'test-blog',
  template: '<h1>Blog page :)</h1>',
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit{

  results: string[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('/api/blog/all').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong there, could you give a [mcve] with a Plunker?

Comment: yes I will look at creating a Plunker then if nothing obvious is standing out. Had me stumped for ages this one.

Comment: @Andrew I'm facing the same issue, any luck with this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Http` import rather than `HttpClient` :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
...
constructor(private http: Http) {}
```

Comment: The `HttpClient` class is valid refer this [**documentation***](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data)

Comment: It depends of the version of Angular. < 4.3 it's just Http

Comment: I was using Http at first but I was getting other errors and then I Found the documentation above and I'm using 4.3.4 so it looks like HttpClient is the one to use.

Answer (score 0):

According to the this [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#injectable-services), your component might missing `@Injectable()`.

Please try this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'test-blog',
  template: '<h1>Blog page :)</h1>',
})

@Injectable()
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit{

results: string[];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('/api/blog/all').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.results = data['results'];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You already [get this for free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494960/component-as-injectable) by using the `Component` decorator (`@Component`).