# Angular Injectable() decorator with @Component decorator

Tags: angular

I am not able to find component decorator's reference to @Injectable decorator included.

When i searched i found below
"A component is injectable by default @Component() (or @Directive()) includes @Injectable()"

@Link to the what i found 
[Component as Injectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494960/component-as-injectable)

But when i checked @Component and @Directive i did not find any reference to @Injectoable.

Could you please help me understand this?

Comment: This may help to you. https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable

Comment: I want to check it in the code where exactly this is referenced

Comment: It is an part of @angular/core. You will easily check code via click that Injectable() with ctrl Button.In your visual studio code editor.

Comment: I can find injectable but my query is where is this referred through component