# add an explicit Angular decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular,
start adding a new component using ng generate component "name"
it works fine
but when i add the `implements OnInit`
the compiler start complains and gives

> Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator

this is my code below:

import { Component, Injectable, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user.model';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-card',
  templateUrl: './address-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-card.cpmponenet.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class AddressCardComponent implements OnInit{
  user: any;
 @Input('user') userDTO?: User;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = {
      name: this.userDTO?.name,
      title: this.userDTO?.designation,
      address: this.userDTO?.address,
      phone:this.userDTO?.phone
    };
  }

}
```

ts version : 4.8.2
angular version: 15.2.4
I have checked stack overflow but nothing helpful... any advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT1:
just try to create a new component:
the ts file look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-card',
  templateUrl: './address-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-card.component.css']
})
export class AddressCardComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

}
```

with an error say under the "AddressCardComponent" says

> Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an
> explicit Angular decorator.

Comment: Why is it `@Component` _and_ `@Injectable`? Typically you'd use the former for components and the latter for _services_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry I have added in order to solve the problem in first place, but aslo did not worked for me

Comment: How are you declaring the component in your module?

Comment: @JSONDerulo I just used the cli command "ng generate component address-card"

Answer (score -1):

Remove `@Injectable()`. That is a decorator used for creating classes that can be injected into other classes using Angular's dependency injection system. It is used for services such as services.

`@Component` however, is a decorator used to create a component. It is used to give Angular information on how to create and use a component. It is used to create components that contain the logic and template for the view of an application that you seem to be doing at the moment.

More explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494992/15439733

Comment: yes dear I have added the injectable as a solve for the problem in firs place, I removed now but still facing the same problem

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It would be best if you provided the original code as well, it would help find the problem.